# common method to check status before all controllers in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application in `cakephp` where a logged in user must have a status of `active` otherwise it should redirect to a controller where user must have submit his application.

Actually i want to implement on all the controllers whenever a user tried to access any controller action it should check the status automatically and if status is not active it should redirect to the user application. How can i implement it in the `Appcontroller`.

My Appcontroller contents are :

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authError' => 'You have been logged out due to period of inactivity.',
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'dashboard'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'logout'
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeFilter` Method in your AppController to perform such a check.
Suppose the name of your Controller where you want to Redirect is `YourController`, then your method should look like.

```
    public function beforeFilter( $event ) {

        if ($this->Auth->user()) { //If User is logged in.
            if ( $this->request->controller != 'YourController' ) { //If Request Controller is other than YourController
                $status  = $this->Auth->user('status'); //Get the Status
                if( $status != 'active' ) { //If Status is not active
                    //Redirect Here
                    return $this->redirect(
                        ['controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'index'];
                    );                  
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually i want to ignore the `login` and `logout` actions which are in the `UsersController`.

Comment: The above check is only for Users who are logged in. So it will automatically ignore the `login` method. If you wan to ignore any other method you can change the condition. Action is available via $this->request->action.

Comment: whenever i want to access the method it is giving me error `Undefined property: ErrorController::$Auth in /var/www/html/app/src/Controller/AppController.php on line 76 [CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 388]`

Comment: are you not using Authentication in your app? There should be a line like $this->loadComponent('Auth') in your initialize function

Comment: Please update the question with contents of your AppController

Comment: Sorry it is working now but i have just noticed that it have changed the default error controller working. For example on wrong controller which is not there it is now giving me error that i have mentioned before rather than it should have stated the missing controller and ctp file error as it was giving before,

Comment: Seems that certain steps are skipped in the error controller, so the Auth component isn't loaded there. Either add an extra check that it's loaded, or else accept that issue, since the error only happens when there's already been an error. :-)

Comment: You should not have `parent::beforeFilter( $event );` in the beforeFilter method of `ErrorController`

Comment: @ascsoftw in my ErrorController `/**
     * beforeFilter callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event Event.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void
     */
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
    }` this is the exact function

Comment: I am not sure then as I am not able to recreate the error that you are getting.

Comment: is there any thing i need to change in the error controller?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything in ErrorController and I don't see the warning that you are seeing when I go to non-existent page.

Comment: @ascsoftw i have checked the error log it is giving me error `Call to a member function user() on boolean` i think this is on `$this->Auth->user()`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt actually i have used simple steps may be there is error in cakephp.

Comment: // for cake 4.2.6 controller can be found                         using    $controllerName = $this->request->getParam('controller');